# can't find Parsec modules in GHCi

Tags: haskell

I've been working on Question [67A of 99 Haskell Questions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/67A). The question is constructing a tree from a given string: `"x(y,a(,b))" => Branch 'x' (Branch 'y' Empty Empty) (Branch 'a' Empty (Branch 'b' Empty Empty))`
One solution using `Parsec` is as below:

```
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec hiding (Empty)

pTree :: Parser (Tree Char)
pTree = do
   pBranch <|> pEmpty

pBranch = do
  a <- letter
  char '('
  t0 <- pTree 
  char ','
  t1 <- pTree
  char ')'
  return $ Branch a t0 t1

pEmpty =
  return Empty

stringToTree str =
  case parse pTree "" str of
     Right t -> t
     Left e  -> error (show e)
```

However, my GHCi could neither find `Text.Parsec.String` nor `Text.Parsec`. Are those modules obsolete? **My GHCi version is 6.12.3**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Text.Parsec` and `Text.Parsec.String` are modules in the [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) package from version 3 on. The old `parsec-2` interface is available from the compatibility modules with the traditional names `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.*`, but there's no `*.String` module, that's new in `parsec-3`. If you have `parsec-2` or no `parsec` at all installed, I recommend installing `parsec-3` with the canonical `cabal install parsec`.

Edit:

If you want to parse a less rigid syntax for the trees, supporting your example input,

```
pBranch = do
  a <- letter
  do char '('
     t0 <- pTree
     char ','
     t1 <- pTree
     char ')'
     return $ Branch a t0 t1
   <|> return (Branch a Empty Empty)
```

defaults to two empty children if the letter is not followed by an opening parenthesis.

Comment: thx, it's compiled ok after installing parsec-3. However, there is an `unexpected "," expecting "("` exception when running it now.

Comment: The input "x(y,a(,b))" cannot be parsed by the given parser, that demands the rigid format "x(y(,),a(,b(,)))" for that tree.

Comment: thx again and I post your solution at 99 questions of Haskell. Is that Ok? If not, I'm gonna delete it immediately

Comment: No problem. If you think it's useful for others, share it.

Answer (score 0):

`Parsec` is found under `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec` instead of `Text.Parsec`.